# Initialize blank array (using keys)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create an array with a dynamic key value and then just adding to the values in the key index like so

```
$age=[];
foreach($alldata as $key=>$item){ // $alldata is just a date array with each age bracket
    foreach($item as $keys=>$ages){ // loop thru each each age per the date
        $age[$keys]=$age[$keys].",".$item[$keys];
    }
}
```

The keys are like so '<1','1-5','6-10' and so on 
But I'm getting the error

```
Undefined index: <1 in ....
```

Do I need to specifically declare the array with the key or am I doing something wrong?

Example $alldata array

```
  ["2020-03-18"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["<1"]=>
    int(0)
    ["1-4"]=>
    int(0)
    ["5-14"]=>
    int(0)
    ["15-24"]=>
    int(0)
    ["25-34"]=>
    int(0)
    ["35-44"]=>
    int(0)
    ["45-54"]=>
    int(0)
    ["55-64"]=>
    int(0)
    ["65+"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["2020-03-19"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["<1"]=>
    int(0)
    ["1-4"]=>
    int(0)
    ["5-14"]=>
    int(0)
    ["15-24"]=>
    int(0)
    ["25-34"]=>
    int(0)
    ["35-44"]=>
    int(0)
    ["45-54"]=>
    int(0)
    ["55-64"]=>
    int(0)
    ["65+"]=>
    int(0)
  }
```

End result should have arrays like

```
$age['<1'] = "0,0,0,0,0,0,0..."
$age['1-4'] = "0,0,0,0,0,0,0..."
...
```

Comment: This solution seems overly complicated. Can you please edit your question showing us an example of your starting input and what you want the output to be?

Comment: More details added

Comment: So what you basically need are age group values throughout all the dates?

Answer (score 0):

So fixed by adding this

```
if (!array_key_exists($keys,$age)){
    $age[$keys]="";
}
```